# how does BLEU score works ? . And how does it differ from the simple Jaccard score based similarity prediction

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, stanford-nlp, nlp

I was trying to understand the concept of BLEU score . 
And then i found this article that had written

"The approach works by counting matching n-grams in the candidate translation to n-grams in the reference text, where 1-gram or unigram would be each token and a bigram comparison would be each word pair."

But that is almost same as when calculating the jaccard score for the similarity scoe b/w two texts .

Could someone explain me how the BLEU score works , and the difference b/w it and the jaccard score based similarity measures .

Comment: I hope there was an answer to this question. Maybe, we need to figure it ourselves.